# AnimatedVectorDrawables pathData not Working?

Tags: android, animation, android-vectordrawable

Actually I was trying to animate a vector drawable (tick to cross and vice versa) but all the pathdata for the svgs that I found doesn't work! even when I use the Android Vector Assets!
I don't know what is the problem? because I am sure that I do extract the pathData correctly but same problem! Always not working. 
The only two pathData that are working are these:

tick: M4.8,13.4 L9,17.6 M10.4,16.2 L19.6,7
cross: M6.4,6.4 L17.6,17.6 M6.4,17.6 L17.6,6.4

But I don't know where they're coming from!. I just copied them from another project!. The pathdata that I found or Android Studio vector assets pathdata are not working.
Could somebody tell me what is the problem and where can I found the exact pathdata or how?

The problem is that: When I run the application It crashes!

At first, I have created my vectors using this XML code:

```
     <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="120dp"
android:height="120dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">

    <group
        android:name="groupTickCross"
        android:pivotX="12"
        android:pivotY="12">

        <path
            android:name="tick"
            android:fillColor="@color/stroke_color"
            android:pathData="@string/path_tick"
            android:strokeWidth="2"
            android:strokeColor="@color/stroke_color"
            android:strokeLineCap="square"
            />

    </group>

</vector>
```

One for the tick and one for the cross, then I created the animation files: cross_to_tick.xml

```
 <objectAnimator
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:propertyName="pathData"
android:valueFrom="@string/path_cross"
android:valueTo="@string/path_tick"
android:duration="450"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
android:valueType="pathType" />
```

and tick_to_cross.xml

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="pathData"
    android:valueFrom="@string/path_tick"
    android:valueTo="@string/path_cross"
    android:duration="450"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"
    android:valueType="pathType" />
```

Rotation animation for both cases:

rotate_cross_to_tick.xml

```
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:valueFrom="-180"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:duration="450"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in" />
```

rotate_tick_to_cross.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="rotation"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="180"
    android:duration="450"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in" />
```

Then I created the files that are going to relate the vectors with animation:
avd_tick_to_cross.xml

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tick">

    <target
        android:name="tick"
        android:animation="@animator/tick_to_cross" />


    <target
        android:name="groupTickCross"
        android:animation="@animator/rotate_tick_to_cross" />

</animated-vector>
```

and avd_cross_to_tick.xml

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_cross">

    <target
        android:name="cross"
        android:animation="@animator/cross_to_tick" />

    <target
        android:name="groupTickCross"
        android:animation="@animator/rotate_cross_to_tick" />

</animated-vector>
```

After that I created the values/tick_cross.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- geometry -->
    <integer name="viewport_width">24</integer>
    <integer name="viewport_height">24</integer>
    <integer name="viewport_center_x">12</integer>
    <integer name="viewport_center_y">12</integer>
    <!--<string name="path_tick">M19.6,7 L10.4,16.2 M4.8,13.4 L9,17.6</string>-->
    <string name="path_tick">M4.8,13.4 L9,17.6 M10.4,16.2 L19.6,7</string>
    <!--<string name="path_cross">M17.6,6.4 L6.4,17.6 M6.4,6.4 L17.6,17.6</string>-->
    <string name="path_cross">M6.4,6.4 L17.6,17.6 M6.4,17.6 L17.6,6.4</string>
    <integer name="stroke_width">2</integer>

    <!-- names -->
    <string name="tick">tick</string>
    <string name="cross">cross</string>
    <string name="groupTickCross">groupTickCross</string>

    <!-- drawing -->
    <color name="stroke_color">#999</color>

    <!-- timing -->
    <integer name="duration">450</integer>

</resources>
```

And the main_activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="animate"
    tools:context="com.example.asma.animatedvectorsdrawables.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tick_cross"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, of course the java class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView tickCross;
    private AnimatedVectorDrawable tickToCross;
    private AnimatedVectorDrawable crossToTick;
    private boolean tick = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tickCross = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tick_cross);

        tickToCross = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.avd_tick_to_cross);
        crossToTick = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.avd_cross_to_tick);

    }

    public void animate(View view) {
        //if it is a tick the animate from tick to cross else? animate from cross to tick
        AnimatedVectorDrawable drawable = tick ? tickToCross : crossToTick;
        tickCross.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        drawable.start();
        tick = !tick;
    }
}
```

This code is working perfectly. But when I change the pathData to another tick/cross pathData extracted from another svg file, the application stops suddenly while running it (only if i use another pathData different from this showed in the code above!)

Here is the pathData of tick and cross that i used (from AndroidStudio VectorAssets)

tick pathData: M9,16.17L4.83,12l-1.42,1.41L9,19 21,7l-1.41,-1.41z

Cross pathData: M19,6.41L17.59,5 12,10.59 6.41,5 5,6.41 10.59,12 5,17.59 6.41,19 12,13.41 17.59,19 19,17.59 13.41,12z

I only change the pathData but keeping all the rest of code as It is.

Thank you

Comment: post some code, how are you using them in your xml/activity

Comment: Define "not working": crash, freeze, unexpected behaviour, hordes of locusts?

Comment: "Not Working" means a crash while running the application.

Comment: I ve added some code in my question. I hope its clear for now. Thank you